# How to couunt categories in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I started a project almost a year ago and created a simple table structure for handling categories and sub-categories with "self-referencing association" if you can call it that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use eloquent's `hasManyThrough` method.
For example, you could create a subProducts method like so,

```
    public function subProducts()
    {
      return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class, Category::class, "categoryId", "parentId");
    }
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer my question?